# Why does nfdt_t type exist in C poll()?

Tags: c, sockets

I'm learning about sockets (in C), and I came accross the system call poll(), which uses `nfds_t` as the type for unsigned int.

```
#include <poll.h>
int poll(struct pollfd fds[], nfds_t nfds, int timeout);
```

I looked into `man poll` , and I found out [this link](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/basedefs/poll.h.html) that sort of mentions it, but it just states it is a typedef used for an unsigned int, not the reason.
My question is: why is this useful or, in case it is not, why would the C POSIX Library do it?

Comment: The document you pointed to says: "*The implementation shall support one or more programming environments in which the width of `nfds_t` is no greater than the width of type `long`.*" Which means different implementations can use whatever types they want for `nfds_t`, as long as they are not larger than `long`. So, the interface of `poll()` needs a single type so people can write portable code.

Comment: I guess I read it but I didn't try to understand what that exactly meant. Thank you for your comment, if you post it as an answer I will mark it.